# Querying by type in DB4O

Tags: c#, .net, function, db4o, argument-passing

How do you pass a class type into a function in C#?

As I am getting into db4o and C# I wrote the following function after reading the tutorials:

```
    public static void PrintAllPilots("CLASS HERE", string pathToDb)
    {
        IObjectContainer db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile(pathToDb);
        IObjectSet result = db.QueryByExample(typeof("CLASS HERE"));
        db.Close();
        ListResult(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are two ways.  The first is to explicitly use the Type type.

```
public static void PrintAllPilots(Type type, string pathToDb)
{
  ...
  IObjectSet result = db.QueryByExample(type);
}

PrintAllPilots(typeof(SomeType),somePath);
```

The second is to use generics

```
public static void PrintAllPilots<T>(string pathToDb)
{
  ...
  IObjectSet result = db.QueryByExample(typeof(T));
}

PrintAllPilots<SomeType>(somePath);
```

Comment: Beat me to the generics. Which gives bonus reusablility for ANY type stored in the db

Answer (score 6):

The answers given by by Jon, Jared, and yshuditelu use query-by-example which is largely unused DB4o querying mechanism, and could potentially be deprecated in the future.

The preferred methods of querying on DB4O for .NET is native queries and LINQ.

```
// Query for all Pilots using DB4O native query:
var result = db.Query<Pilot>();
```

Or alternatively using Linq-to-DB4O:

```
// Query for all Pilots using LINQ
var result = from Pilot p in db
             select p;
```

Both of these work provided you know the type (e.g. Pilot) at compile time. If you don't know the type at compile time, you can instead use a DB4O SODA query:

```
var query = db.Query();
query.Constrain(someObj.GetType());
var results = query.Execute();
```

*edit* Why use LINQ instead of SODA, Query-by-Example (QBE), or Native Query (NQ)? Because LINQ makes it very natural to do query expressions. For example, here's how you'd query for pilots named Michael:

```
var michaelPilots = from Pilot p in db
                    where p.Name == "Michael"
                    select p;
```

And LINQ is composable, meaning you can do things like this:

```
var first20MichaelPilots = michaelPilots.Take(20);
```

And you'll still get an efficient query executed in DB4O when you iterate over the results. Doing the same in SODA or QBE or NQ is ugly at best.

Comment: I have already worked with LINQ and have to admit that it is eye candy in all aspects. Will digg into native query as the next step. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: I've modified the post to explain why LINQ is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
public static void PrintAllPilots(Type classType, string pathToDb)
{
    IObjectContainer db = Db4oFactory.OpenFile(pathToDb);
    IObjectSet result = db.QueryByExample(classType);
    db.Close();
    ListResult(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either do it manually by using `Type`:

```
public static void PrintAllPilots(Type type, string pathToDb)
```

Or you could use generics to infer the type:

```
public static void PrintAllPilots<T>(string pathToDb)
{
   //...
   var result = db.QueryByExample(typeof(T));
}
```